# Why are things like cin, cout, string, etc. considered objects?

Tags: c++, c++11

From what I understand (and what my textbook says), an object is a programming element that is self-contained, which holds data and a procedure that performs an operation on that data. With this being said, why are things like cin, cout, string, etc. considered objects? Is cin an object, in the way that I defined? Is cin the name of a self-contained unit, which holds data and a procedure that performs operations on that data, found within the source code of the iostream header file?

Comment: [`cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) and [`cout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) are different from `string` in that they are *instances* of a class, whereas `string` is a class.

Comment: `std::string` is not an object, it's a type-alias for `std::basic_string<char>`. And [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a *class*. [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) and [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) are special instances of the [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) and [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) classes, respectively.

Comment: Faulty assumption 1: `string` is not considered an object. Faulty assumption 2: "considered", because the C++ standard defines the term object precisely.

Comment: @alan Note that the definition of object in C++ may differ to that found in other languages, especially OOP ones. In C++ an object is basically anything that takes space and isn't a function.

Answer (score 11):

`cin` and `cout` are variables, and as such they're objects.

An **object**, in C++, is a not-necessarily contiguous region of storage, with an associated content interpretation in the form of a type.

This is a term defined by the C++ standard.

**C++11 §1.8/1**

> **”** The constructs in a C ++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. An *object* is a
>   region of storage. [*Note:* A function is not an object, regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the
>   way that objects do. *—end note* ] An object is created by a *definition* (3.1), by a *new-expression* (5.3.4) or
>   by the implementation (12.2) when needed. The properties of an object are determined when the object is
>   created. An object can have a *name* (Clause 3). An object has a *storage duratio*n (3.7) which influences
>   its *lifetime* (3.8). An object has a *type* (3.9). The term *object type* refers to the type with which the object
>   is created. Some objects are *polymorphic* (10.3); the implementation generates information associated with
>   each such object that makes it possible to determine that object’s type during program execution. For other
>   objects, the interpretation of the values found therein is determined by the type of the *expressions* (Clause 5)
>   used to access them.

The non-contiguous thing was primarily in support of multiple inheritance, but at least one committee member argued strongly, in a discussion with me, that it was intended to support making objects in general non-contiguous. However, I know of no extant compiler that does that. It seems meaningless to me.

`std::string` is not an object, it's a type.

---

Note: with some other programming languages, and in computer science in general, the term “object” often denotes *an instance of a class type*. In C++ even instances of non-class types such as `int`, are objects.

Comment: Now you touched a very intersting topic. Since object can be accessed as a character array, how this access is supposed to work in case of non-continguos objects?

Comment: This is a very thorough explanation that addresses terms that I think the OP didn't even consider. Kudos to a great answer!

Comment: @SergeyA: I'm not sure, but C++11 §1.8/5 says " An object of trivially copyable or standard-layout type (3.9) shall occupy contiguous bytes of storage."

Comment: What do you mean `not-necessarily contiguous`. I would have thought it was a contiguous section of memory (not counting pointers to other distinct objects). Unless you are referring to compiler added padding?

Comment: @LokiAstari: The classical example is`X` inherits `A` and `B` which both inherit virtually from `Top`. Then at most one of the `A` and `B` sub-objects can be contiguous, the other must be spread around a bit. Which is (one reason) why virtual inheritance imposes a run time cost. I agree that it makes no sense in other situations. :)

Comment: OK. I was going to argue against that. But as I wrote it down I realized that getting a reference to an `A` and `B` coming from an instance of `X` is going to have one of them in a nasty chopped up state. OK. Glad  I am no longer writing compilers that's just nasty.

Answer (score 1):

They are considered objects, because they are "objects". They are not types, they are instances.

You can see how they are defined [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

Example:

```
extern std::istream cin;
extern std::wistream wcin;
```

As you can see, `cin` is a variable whose type is `std::istream`.

Regarding your assumption about `std::string`: again, [cppreference is very helpful](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

We can see that `std::string` is not a variable/object, but a type alias for `std::basic_string<char>` instead.

Comment: Also address his assumption about `string` in your answer.